# how to delete all the data in a sheet in excel?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, python-3.10

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("C:\op.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
```

This is the code I have so far as I don't know what to do next so pls help me.

Comment: Why not simply create a new file instead and overwrite the existing one?

Comment: We wrote a program to remove all the files in a directory structure and it took about 2 hours to run. Then we realized removing the parent directory and creating a new directory structure was much quicker - like 5 seconds...

Comment: Why not delete the sheet, then create a new sheet.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
ws.delete_rows(1, ws.max_row)
```

You could also delete the sheet and create another one:

```py
del wb[wb.active.title]
wb.create_sheet()
```

See

- https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.delete_rows
- https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.create_sheet